# Control may reach end of non-void function. C

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors, cs50

I am getting the above error on the return line of this code.

```
// Finds the length of the card number 
int find_length(long long n)
{
    int len;
    for (len = 0; n != 0; n /= 10, len++)
    return len;
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <unistd.h>



void print_credit_card_brand(long long ccn);
bool check_validity(long long credit_card_number);
int find_length(long long n);
bool checksum(long long ccn);



int main(void)
{
    long long credit_card_number;
    do
    {
        credit_card_number = get_long_long("Enter valid credit card number without spaces or hyphens: ");
    } while (credit_card_number < 0);

    if (check_validity(credit_card_number) == true)
        print_credit_card_brand(credit_card_number);
    else
        printf("INVALID\n");
}



// Checks validity of credit card
bool check_validity(long long credit_card_number)
{
    int len = find_length(credit_card_number);
    return (len == 13 || len == 15 || len == 16) && checksum(credit_card_number);
}



// Finds the length of the card number 
int find_length(long long n)
{
    int len;
    for (len = 0; n != 0; n /= 10, len++)
    return len;
}



// Determines validity using Luhn’s Algorithm
bool checksum(long long ccn)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i =0; ccn != 0; i++, ccn /=  10)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
             sum += ccn % 10;
        else
        {
            int digit = 2 * (ccn % 10);
            sum += digit / 10 + digit % 10;
        }
    }
    return (sum % 10) == 0;
}



// Prints results besed on length of credit card and 1st 2 digits
void print_credit_card_brand(long long ccn)
{
    if ( (ccn >= 34e13 && ccn < 35e13) || (ccn >= 37e13 && ccn < 38e13) )
        printf("AMEX\n");
    else if (ccn >= 51e14 && ccn < 56e14)
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    else if ( (ccn >= 4e12 && ccn < 5e12) || (ccn >= 4e15 && ccn < 5e15) )
        printf("VISA\n");
    else
        printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Comment: Hint: What does your function return if n is 0?

Comment: @Alex_2539 You forgot a semicolon after the for loop.

Comment: IMHO a while loop will be easier to read

Comment: And this is why ***always*** using braces for every loop and if-statement is a good idea.  A construct that ***always*** looks the same is much easier to understand.  Your brain sees the pattern instantly.  Unlike in this case where you brain completely missed the pattern.

Comment: As a matter of style, making sure always to use blocks for loop bodies helps avoid this kind of error, and, others, too.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to place a semicolon after the for loop. So with this typo the function looks like

```
int find_length(long long n)
{
    int len;
    for (len = 0; n != 0; n /= 10, len++)
    {
        return len;
    }
}
```

The function can look for example the following way

```
unsigned int find_length( unsigned long long n )
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;
    unsigned int len = 0;

    for ( ; n != 0; n /= Base )
    {
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}
```

Pay attention to that you should use unsigned integer types. Otherwise the user can enter a negative number and your program will produce a wrong result.

Comment: Thanks! Your revised version of my loop returned the same error but your rewritten version did not. Very helpful! Thanks again!